How probable is an infinite sequence of heads? by Williamson
I was reading  Timothy Williamson's paper "How probable is an infinite sequence of heads" when I stumbled over the following claim on page 177 (6th page of the pdf):

I am concerned with the first alleged logical equivalence and I just cannot make sense of the "appropriate definitions" bit, because the truth table just flat out contradicts Williamson's claim that these are logically equivalent.

Let "~" be the negation sign.
If H(1...) corresponds to p, (~H(1)) to q, and H(2...) to r, the truth table yields a different result.
I tried to convince myself that in the second row one might be able to arrive a the correct truth value:
Assigned truth values: H(1...) is false, ~H(1) is false and H(2...) is true. Then the expanded formula looks like this:
(H(1...) v ~H(1)) & (H(1...) v H(2...))
Let us look at the second half first:
H(2...) is true and means "the event that every toss after the first comes head"
H(1...) is false and means "the event that every toss comes head"
~H(1) means just the event that the first toss does not come head
From these two propositions it follows that the first toss does not come heads. Hence, ~H(1)  is true, in contradiction to its originally assigned truth value. If we continue to hold ~H(1) to be true, I can see how at least in the second row H(2...) has the same truth value as the expanded formula.
But first, why accept this change in truth values for ~H(1) and not evaluate the first half of the expanded formula according to the original assigned truth values? Second, rows 5 and 7 still contradict Williamson's claim of equivalence as H(2...) is in both rows false whereas the expanded formula comes out as true.
What is Williamson's reasoning behind his claim of equivalence?

This looks a lot like a discussion of a meaningless concept, that is, "objective probabilities" without even guesses about objective priors.

@gs, you may be right, but there is a series of papers on this published in apparently leading journals such as Synthese and elsewhere, including a steady trickle of recent publications.

@MikhailKatz I may be wrong, but I would trust the pseudo-speech vocalizations of pet parrot over most things published in a leading philosophy journal.

@gs, some of the work involved does tend to furnish support for your attitude.  But (1) we happen to be at a philosophy SE, and (2) such published work does influence people's views on things, and if only for that reason needs to be taken more seriously (than it perhaps deserves).  I am also aware of valuable work published in leading philosophy journals :-)

H(1...) ∨ (¬H(1) ∧ H(2...)) is true when all tosses are heads or when the first is tails and the rest are heads. This is equivalent to saying that all tosses after the first are heads, and can be easily derived by Boolean algebra after noting that H(1...) = H(1) ∧ H(2...) (i.e. all tosses are heads when the first is heads and those after are also heads). Just factor out H(2...) and use that H(1) ∨ ¬H(1) = ⊤ by LEM. Truth values of H(1), H(1...) and H(2...) cannot be assigned independently, so some rows of the truth table for p, q, r are irrelevant.

Humans have had 100 billion heads so far. We lost a few in the French Revolution though.

@ScottRowe: No tails though.  A clear imbalance.  Perhaps the problem is ill-posed.

If P(heads) < 1, $\lim_{n->\infty} P(heads)^n = 0$. If P(heads) = 1, $\lim_{n->\infty} P(heads)^n = 1$. Therefore the probability that an infinite sequence of independent throws will be all heads is exactly equal to the probability that it's a two-headed coin. (P(two-headed) * 1 + P(~two-headed) * 0). Why did Williamson spend 8 pages on this?

Your truth table does not correctly represent what is going on here. For the benefit of those who haven't looked at the paper, H(1) denotes the result of heads on the first toss. H(1...) denotes the first toss and all subsequent tosses being heads. H(2...) denotes the second toss and all subsequent tosses being heads.
Try looking at it this way.
H(1) ∨ ¬H(1) is a tautology. So,
(H(1) ∨ ¬H(1)) ∧ H(2...) is logically equivalent to H(2...)
Hence by the distributivity of conjunction over disjunction,
(H(1) ∧ H(2...)) ∨ (¬H(1) ∧ H(2...)) is logically equivalent to H(2...)
But we also have
H(1) ∧ H(2...) is logically equivalent to H(1...)
Since both of those correspond to getting a heads on the first toss and then a heads on all subsequent tosses. So, by subtitution we get Williamson's
H(1...) ∨ (¬H(1) ∧ H(2...)) is logically equivalent to H(2...)

What I don't get is why is this helpful explanation not given? He explains all the other details in the derivations in the paper.

Here Williamson is assuming that the Markoff shift n -> n+1 preserves his function H.  This genre of philosophizing is fundamentally flawed, because it assumes that a particular type of infinity is necessarily used in modeling pre-mathematical phenomena of a vast plurality of trials, such as coin tosses.  Williamson's assumption presupposes the outcome of his philosophical analysis, and in this sense is circular.  One way of describing the error is that Williamson is assuming that an infinite number is necessarily a Cantorian cardinal, and neglects the possibility that it may be a ringinal, namely a number greater than any naive counting integer, such as nonstandard numbers that occur in Robinson's framework.  A related issue was discussed in this question.  We have a forthcoming article analyzing the views of Williamson and his pen pals; I will keep you posted.

First, I am a layman and I do not know what a Markoff shift is. Where can I read more? Second, before I doubt Williamson's premises, I first would like to understand his reasoning. You reject his conclusion and attack his argument by pointing to a false premise. I am at the stage of just trying to understand his reasoning given his assumptions about the nature of infinity.

In developing set theory, Cantor used the principle of 1-1 correspondence to define the cardinality of a set.  From this point of view, the natural numbers N={1,2,3,...} would be in 1-1 correspondence with the set {2,3,4,...} just by shifting n to n+1 (that's what's called a Markoff shift but you don't need to use the term).  The unspoken assumption here is that a vast plurality of coin tosses must necessarily be modeled by an infinite cardinal, such as the cardinality of N.  But it doesn't have to be.

But how does Williamson arrive at the equivalence? What would Williamson say if I posed the question to him?

Well you would have to ask him :-) but I imagine he would say something along the following lines: if you toss coin1, then coin2, then coin3, etc.  then the probability of all heads should be the same as when you toss coin2, then coin3, then coin4, etc., since these these are equivalent processes.  But the claim of equivalence rests on his assumption that a vast plurality of trials must be modeled mathematically by an infinite cardinal rather than a ringinal.
